# how to create a preview version of a multi-page pdf in carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

In carrierwave (1.2.1) using MiniMagick, a simple "process convert: png" will convert a spreadsheet, word doc, or single page pdf into a png file.  However, the whole thing chokes when processing a multi-page pdf.  I wish MiniMagick made some assumptions and automatically converted page 1.  This seems like a fairly common usage...and, yet there seem to be many ideas on how to do it...and, none of them seem to work.  ImageMagick seems to have better support for this.  But, alas...I am using MiniMagick.  Back in carrierwave 0.11.2 (not sure what version of MiniMagick), a multi-page PDF would assume page 1...and, create a preview png using this same version code.  Not anymore.

```
version :large do
  process convert: 'png'
  process :set_png_content_type
  process resize_to_limit: [1024, 1024]
  def full_filename(for_file = model.receipt.file)
    super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '_large' + '.png'
  end
end
```

The code above will successfully convert a single-page PDF named "my_pdf_file.pdf" into a png version named "my_pdf_file_large.png"

However, that version will fail if the pdf supplied is multi-page.
Partial stack trace:

```
Validation failed: Asset Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? 
Original Error: `identify /Users/secret/Sites/secret/tmp/1514239240-67574-0020-1237/large/agency_card.png` 
failed with error: identify: improper image header `/Users/secret/Sites/secret/tmp/1514239240-67574-0020-1237/large/agency_card.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/4227.
```

The error "improper image header" occurs (per reliable sources) when the image isn't found.  In this case I'm assuming it isn't being found in the cache (tmp directory)?

## - - - - - - - - - - - -

If I change the version to this:

```
version :large do
  process convert: 'jpg'
  process :set_jpg_content_type
  process resize_to_limit: [1024, 1024]
  def full_filename(for_file = model.receipt.file)
    super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '_large' + '.jpg'
  end
end
```

I get a different error:

```
 Validation failed: Asset Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? 
 Original Error: `identify /Users/secret/Sites/secret/tmp/1514240098-67574-0022-1346/large/agency_card.jpg` 
 failed with error: identify: insufficient image data in file `/Users/secret/Sites/secret/tmp/1514240098-67574-0022-1346/large/agency_card.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/ReadJPEGImage/1069.
```

So, my question is this:  why is there not a uniformed way (baked in to MiniMagick preferably) to handle converting multi-page PDF documents.  Some people want to convert each page of the PDF, while others just want the first page.  This feels like magic...and, it should be easy.

Is there a smart, simple way to accomplish this using MiniMagick?

Rails 5.1.4
Carrierwave 1.2.1
Ghostscript
Heroku
Ruby 2.4.3
MiniMagick

## - - - - - UPDATE - - - - -

The error "improper image header" indicates that the image can't be found.  The path in the error message:

```
 `/Users/secret/Sites/secret/tmp/1514240098-67574-0022-1346/large/agency_card.jpg'
```

but, should actually be (and, the image does actually exist here):

```
 `/Users/secret/Sites/secret/tmp/uploads/1514240098-67574-0022-1346/agency_card.jpg'
```

my carrierwave config does set config.cache_dir = "#{ Rails.root }/tmp/uploads"...which is not being used when the image is retrieved from cache (tmp).  And, I'm not sure where the version name in the path comes from...but, no subdirectories exist in my tmp directory named for the version name.

Comment: If you just want page 1 of the PDF, then try adding [0] after the filename (e.g. image.pdf[0]) to load only the first page from the PDF. ImageMagick requires the use of Ghostscript to read PDF files. So you must have Ghostscript installed. I presume minimagick is the same.

Comment: I'll try that.  I should have mentioned that I do have GS installed.  THANKS!

Comment: @fmw42 I'm not using manipulate! in this version, so I don't have access to the MiniMagick image object.  In order to use "image.pdf[0]" do I need to create my own convert method using manipulate!?  ...or, can I incorporate that into the version as shown above?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I do not know minimagick, only ImageMagick.

Comment: Hi.. Could you figure this out ?

Comment: Not resolved, yet.  I was not able to create my own buildpack...and, I know the Heroku team is working on it..  There are some mutool licensing issues....hopefully soon.